# How to use Mongoid Enum

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, enums

I'm trying to use [Mongoid Enum](https://github.com/thetron/mongoid-enum) and am struggling with something. Here's my Model:

```
class Notification

  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps
  include Mongoid::Enum
  enum :status, [:new, :viewed]
  ...

end
```

When I try to create a new object like so:

```
notification = Notification.create({ title: "Some title", content: "Some content" })
```

I'm getting `wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)` on the line where the above code is. I don't get it. I still get the error when I try:

```
notification = Notification.create({ title: "Some title", content: "Some content", status: :new })
```

OR

```
notification = Notification.create({ title: "Some title", content: "Some content", :status => :new })
```

OR

```
notification = Notification.create({ title: "Some title", content: "Some content", status: 'new' })
```

The only way I can create the object is if I remove the enum from my Model.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem when :new is one of the valid symbols for the enum.  When I changed :new to :default, it began working.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using `rails 5` and `mongoid 6.1` and want to use `mongoid-enum` you definitely going to have a tough day.

I finally found a solution to cop this, you need to mention this

```
gem 'mongoid-enum', git: 'git@github.com:boie0025/mongoid-enum', branch: 'nb/mongoid-6'
```

insight your Gemfile.

Answer (score 1):

This is because NEW is a reserved word and it cannot be used like that, but you can use something else like xxx_new.

Btw, I'm aware that this post is from one year ago, but maybe it can help someone else with the same problem.